# What should MiniTest::Spec files be named?

Tags: ruby, naming-conventions, specifications, minitest

I want to use MiniTest::Spec, I found a couple resources to get started, but none of them mentioned what the test files (or spec files) should be named, and where they should be placed:

- `test/test_*`
- `spec/*_spec.rb`

So which one should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using rake you can specify your own path in the rake file e.g.

```
 Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.libs << "test"
  t.test_files = FileList['test/test_*.rb']
  t.verbose = true
end
```

Comment: So what's the default?

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you obviously, but I'd recommend using `spec/**/*_spec.rb` -- the thinking here being, if MiniTest::Spec is modeled after RSpec in syntax, then you might as well put the tests in the same place that RSpec puts them so people won't be put off guard.